# How to do enrichment of an object in reactor webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have an interface

```
    public interface Enricher {
       Mono<MyObject> enrich(MyObject obj);
    }
```

I have implementations of this interface which returns the updated MyObject.

I have another implementation called **CompositeEnricher** which takes in List of Enricher in constructor and performs enrichment.

In non-reactive world, I will write something like this

```
/*
  Please note that following code is applicable only if Enricher interface returns MyObject instead of Mono<MyObject>
*/

public class CompositeEnricher implements Enricher {

  private final List<Enricher> enrichers;

  public CompositeEnricher(List<Enricher> enrichers) {
    this.enrichers = enrichers;
  }

  @Override
  public MyObject enrich(MyObject myObject) {
    MyObject updated = myObject;
    for(Enricher enricher : enrichers) {
      updated = enricher.enrich(updated);
    }
    return updated;
  }
}
```

How do I change it to reactive so that each of the implementations of Enricher return Mono including CompositeEnricher which implements Enricher interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem using Mono.expand method. But I had to use enrichers.iterator(). Wondering if I can somehow put enrichers also in reactive chain instead of using iterator.

```
@Override
    public Mono<User> enrich(User user) {
        Iterator<Enricher> iterator = enrichers.iterator();
        Function<User, Publisher<User>> enrichmentFunction = u -> iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next().enrich(u) : Mono.empty();
        return Mono.just(user)
                .expand(enrichmentFunction)
                .last();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's actually no need for a separate `CompositeEnricher` class here at all - given a `List<Enricher> enrichers`, you can simply reduce your enrichers using standard Java streams:

```
Enricher composite = enrichers.stream()
        .reduce((e1, e2) -> myObj -> e1.enrich(myObj).flatMap(myObj2 -> e2.enrich(myObj2)))
        .get();
```

You can flesh this out into a class if you need to of course, but you could equally just leave this implemented as a helper method somewhere.

Comment: Actually I wanted to use reactive of of doing this since my enrich method return Mono<MyObject> instead of just MyObject.

Comment: @AvikKesari Not sure what you mean - the approach here will still give you an `enrich()` method which returns a `Mono<MyObject>`?

Comment: Please see the solution I posted using Mono.expand. I was wondering if I can improve this solution and put enrichers also in reactive chain

Comment: @AvikKesari As far as I can tell, you're aiming to use reactive chains when there's no advantage in doing so - unless the enrichers are obtained somehow via a reactive stream, rather than being supplied as a list?

Comment: Actually one of my enrichers does an blocking rmi call to other service and I am trying to wrap that inside reactive chain so that I don't get exception in Blockhound. For that I have wrapped changed my interface to return Mono instead of being blocking.

Comment: @AvikKesari Yup, completely understand that - but the above code should give you a single Enricher which reactively chains all the `enrich()` methods (in a non-blocking fashion, so you shouldn't get any blocking or blockhound issues.) Have you tried it? The only reason the above approach wouldn't work is if you have a `Flux<Enricher>` that you need to combine rather than a `List<Enricher>`.